# ILMERGE icon for final .exe

Tags: icons, ilmerge

I have a couple of dlls and an .exe file (call it input.exe). These are currently merged into a single output.exe file using ILMERGE.

The input.exe file has an icon with it. 
However the output.exe that is created does not have  the icon in input.exe

So to sum it up, I would like to have an icon for the output.exe (that is created using ILMERGE)

Could you help me figure this out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify input.exe as your primary assembly (the first assembly specified in the command line) and it should include the icon in the merged executable.

At least it does so with the version I'm using: 2.9.210.0.

Answer (score -3):

Why not use [a tool](http://www.shelllabs.com/) and make the icon anything you want?

Comment: That looks more like an explorer hack.